# sql query not working with concat

Tags: mysql

i am working on a search system in which a person is searched by country and their firstname and the last name. For the First and Last name i used `concat`but using it with further and condition doesn't seems to work. my query is

```
select * from users_profile where CONCAT(fname,' ',lname) like '%v %'
or Email like '%v %' AND country='india'
```

in the above if ise use the query without "and" it works . but i need to specify more conditions and if i simply use and without `concat` that also works .

```
select * from users_profile where CONCAT(fname,' ',lname) like '%v %'
or Email like '%v %'
```

how to make it work with both `concat`  and further `and condition` i want to apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be using `CONCAT`, let alone any functions around your `WHERE` columns. Further, you should be specifying a column list, not `SELECT *`. Also check your order of criteria.

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT fullname, Email, country
FROM
    (SELECT CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname) AS fullname, Email, country FROM users_profile) a
WHERE (a.fullname LIKE '%v %' OR Email LIKE '%v ') AND country = 'india'
```

Comment: Functions are fine in a `WHERE` clause, as long as you know the impact (no use of indexes) or if they evaluate to a constant (dumb example: `DATE(NOW())`).

Comment: @AlainCollins To me, the no use of indexes seems like an obvious no-no in query tuning.

Comment: It's a red flag - just like `DISTINCT` - but it's perfectly fine when you get a constant.

Comment: kk after some tries i found that it was a space issue if the user entered only the first name then using concat it was putting up extra space which was causing trouble. any help on this?

Comment: Trim the input before you go searching?

Comment: no if i do that and if user puts up space in between first and last name then that space would be removed. should i use left trim and right trim for that?

Comment: @ParamVeer As Alain suggests, trimming would remove any white spaces. You may also want to use other wildcard characters such as `_`. `LIKE '%v_%'`

Comment: @param, trim functions only affect the start or end (or both) of the string, not the middle.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up for me @AlainCollins i didnt knew it . :)

Comment: Java's [trim](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) does both sides.   Perl's [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) only does the end.

Answer (score 1):

AND has a higher precedence than OR, so you need to group your statements more logically.

Something like:

```
select * from users_profile where (CONCAT(fname,' ',lname) like '%v %'
or Email like '%v %') AND country='india'
```

should work.

Comment: your idea further helped me in making it more flexible . thank you :)